# ActionMailer::Base Dynamic :from email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

How can I change this code in my email mailer so that when current_user sends out an email from the application it is received by the recipient :from => current_user.email.

Currently it is from "notification@example.com" but I would like this to change dynamically and Is this possible without resulting in emails going into junk?

```
class EmailMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "notification@example.com"

    def email_listing(user, listing, email)
        @user = user 
        @listing = listing
        @email = email
        @url  = "www.example.com"

        mail(:to => @email.email, :subject => @user.name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just pass the from option to add a custom from address, and pass the reply_to option for a reply address into the mail method, like

```
def email_listing(user, listing, email)
  @user = user 
  @listing = listing
  @email = email
  @url  = "www.example.com"

  mail(:to => @email.email, :subject => @user.name, from: 'notification@example.com', reply_to: @user.email)
end
```

Comment: When I do :from => @user.email, It doesn't work. The email still says from: "origina@example.com" - the email I have set up in the config not the users emails

Comment: What is the error? Be wary of sending emails from other user's addresses. Usually the from address is some sitewide address, like 'donotreply@example.com' (so it doesn't appear that the user is sending another user an email, ie if the recipient tries to reply).

Comment: How do I get the recepient to simply click reply and have the email get sent to the sending user and not the websites email

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to send an email from user1@example.com to user2@example.com, and when user2@example.com replies, it should go to user1@example.com? I would advise sending the email from notifications@yourapp.com, with a reply-to set to user1@example.com.

check out [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help that solves it. Please add the :reply_to=> to your answer.